# Cloud Code Array Parameter Size Limit

Tags: parse-platform

I'm wondering if there is a limit to the size/length of an array used in a "notContained" query.

Here's my example: 
I'm passing an array with objectIds from my iOS app to my Cloud Code to build a query to check for records that have not been displayed in my app and then query for records whose objectId is not in this list:

...
var displayedIds = request.params.displayedIds;
query.notContainedIn("objectId", displayedIds);
...

So my question is, should I limit my array to a certain length, e.g. 1000 entries, as to not slow down the query itself or how problematic will that be for the server if the array grows beyond a couple thousand entries?

Any ideas?

Best,
Martin.